# Update a field in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x

I have a piece of code which follows this form.  Is this correct or is there a better way?

```
for i, c in enumerate(contacts):
    fullname = c['Person__FirstName'] + ' ' + c['Person__LastName']
    contacts[i]['fullname'] = create_a_tag('/contact/'+str(c['PersonSk']), fullname)
```

Comment: I don't see why this should be closed. Short entries of code, that do follow Code Review rules, [are on-topic](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1588/35559).

Comment: @AlexL because of example code. You don't have `foofield` in a real application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the feeling that there's some context information missing. Anyway, note that `list_of_dictionaries[i]` is actually the same object as `r`.

The same code with some variables renamed would be as follows:

```
for index, dictionary in enumerate(dictionaries):
    dictionary['foofield'] = foofinder(dictionary['barfield'], dictionary['bazfield'])
```

In the new code the index is not used at all, so the code could be simplified as follows:

```
for dictionary in dictionaries:
    dictionary['foofield'] = foofinder(dictionary['barfield'], dictionary['bazfield'])
```

Comment: I had thought in this way that dictionary was a copy just scoped to the loop.  Glad to learn that's not the case.

Comment: Ok, I see. For the future, you can test that assumption as follows: `for index, dictionary in enumerate(dictionaries): print dictionary is dictionaries[i]`